# Tournament Generator PHP

Tags: php, image, tournament

I found this package and I am trying to run the example and the show the bracket.

But it outputs some weird characters:

```
�PNG  IHDR�Ht�4PLTE���U��~�IDATx����o�V��GIW&q�*�=ު`B�&��?�?!R*Mv�
```

You get the point.

I am thinking that it's because:

```
// If GD-lib is installed, the below code will draw the bracket of the knock-out      tournament.
if ($GDLIB_INSTALLED) {
$im = $KO->getImage("Tournament name here");
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
}
```

But I dont know how to fix it....

Thanks,
Ara

EDIT:

So I changed the code a bit after what gat said.

In my controller, I got:
public function getTest(){

```
    // Depending on whether or not GD-lib is installed this example file will output differently.
    $GDLIB_INSTALLED = (function_exists("gd_info")) ? true : false;


    // Lets create a knock-out tournament between some of our dear physicists.
    $competitors = array(
        'Paul A.M. Dirac', 
        'Hans Christian Oersted', 
        'Murray Gell-Mann', 
        'Marie Curie', 
        'Neils Bohr', 
        'Richard P. Feynman', 
        'Max Planck');

    // Create initial tournament bracket.
    $KO = new TournamentGeneratorGD($competitors);
    $KO->setResByMatch(1, 1, 4, 0);


    if($GDLIB_INSTALLED){
        $im = $KO->getImage("Tournament name here");
        return View::make('test_img')
                    ->with('im', $im);
    }
    else
        return View::make('home');
}
```

And in my test_img.php page, I got this:

```
<?php   
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

It doesnt work anyway..

Comment: Do you have the GD library installed?

Comment: Is that all the code? because it seems like the header is not being applied, wheres the headers already sent error? ;p

Comment: @Lawrence, no it's not all the code. But I changed it after what gat said and it didn't fix it tho...

Answer (score 1):

`header('Content-type: image/png');` should be the first thing you say before outputting anything else.

Try moving the following code to a different source file (img.php or something).

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
$im = $KO->getImage("Tournament name here");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

You may then redirect the page to img.php in your `if ($GDLIB_INSTALLED)` block.

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it didn't work... I just put this:  <?php   
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
?>